# Root test related: show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}|a_k|^{1/k}=\lim_{\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}|a_{k+1}|^{1/k}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've been trying to do the following proofs as an excercise.

> Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}|a_k|^{1/k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}|a_{k+1}|^{1/k}$$

This is what i have done so far:

Assume $\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=L_1$ exists and $\lim_{n \to \infty}|\sup a_{k+1}|^{1/k}=L2$ . Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there and exists integer $N_1$ s.t. $||a_n|^{1/n}-L_1|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N_1$.  Similarly, for the same $\epsilon>0$ there exists integer $N_2$ s.t. $|\sup |a_{k+1}|^{1/k}-L_2|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N_2$. Let $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$. For any $n>N$,

$|\sup |a_{k+1}|^{1/k}-|\sup |a_{k}|^{1/k}|=$ 
$|\sup |a_{k+1}|^{1/k}-L_1+L_1-L_2+L_2+|\sup |a_{k}|^{1/k}|$
$|\sup |a_{k+1}|^{1/k}-L_1+(L_1-L_2)+(L_2-|\sup |a_{k}|^{1/k}$
which is less than $2\epsilon+|L_1-L_2|$. I need to show $L_1=L_2$ which is the heart of the question. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Use `\to` to produce $\to$. Also use `\sup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we're taking absolute values, why not just say that $a_k\ge0$.

By substituting $k\mapsto k-1$ then $n\mapsto n-1$, we get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}a_{k+1}^{1/k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}a_k^{1/(k-1)}\tag{1}
$$
Note that for $k\ge m$, $\frac1{k-1}$ is between $\frac1k$ and $\frac1k\frac{m}{m-1}$. Therefore, for $n\ge m$,
$$
\sup_{k\ge n}a_k^{1/(k-1)}
\quad\text{is between}\quad
\sup_{k\ge n}a_k^{1/k}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\sup_{k\ge n}a_k^{1/k\,\cdot\,m/(m-1)}\tag{2}
$$
Therefore, for any $m$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}a_k^{1/(k-1)}
\quad\text{is between}\quad
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}a_k^{1/k}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}a_k^{1/k}\right)^{m/(m-1)}\tag{3}
$$
Since this is true for any $m$, $(1)$ and $(3)$ imply
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}a_{k+1}^{1/k}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}a_k^{1/(k-1)}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}a_k^{1/k}\tag{4}
$$

Comment: if the seqence a_k is {1,1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5}, i don't see how (2) can still be true. For instance, $\sup a_k^{1/k}$ would equal 1 but sup a_k^{1-k}=1/2 (which is not greater than 1) and so (2) doesn't seem to hold for sequences of elements less than 1. Any more help would greatly be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Pick and $m$, say $m=2$. $(2)$ says that for $n\ge2$, say $n=3$, $\sup\limits_{k\ge 3}a_k^{1/(k-1)}=0.668740304976422$ is between $\sup\limits_{k\ge 3}a_k^{1/k}=0.724779663677696$ and $\sup\limits_{k\ge 3}a_k^{2/k}=0.525305560880753$.

Comment: Oh... I see it now!  Thanks!!!!!!!